# DISTINCT WITH SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have a mysql join result which looks like this.

```
ID | Name | Score | SomeID
---------------------------
1  | abc  |  100  |  2 
1  | abc  |  100  |  2
1  | abc  |  100  |  3
1  | abc  |  100  |  3
1  | abc  |  100  |  4
1  | abc  |  100  |  4
```

I want the result of this join result in sum as distinct 
Like

```
ID | Name | SUM(Score) | SomeID
---------------------------
1  | abc  |    200     |  2
1  | abc  |    200     |  3
1  | abc  |    200     |  4
```

Is there any possible solution to this problem! Any Help?

Comment: I cannot believe that you actually tried anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Score), SomeID
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY ID, Name, SomeID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need sum and group by

```
select
id,
name,
sum(Score) as total,
SomeID
from table_name
group by Name,SomeID
```

UPDATE :
Mysql has flexibility to have columns in the selection while using the aggregate function and then not using them in group by

But many RDBMS will not like it and in that case you must add them in group by clause. So as a standard it should be as -

`group by id, Name,SomeID`

Comment: To be fully SQL standard compliant, it should be `GROUP BY id, name, SomeID`, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT ID,
         Name,
         SUM(Score) total,
         SomeID
    FROM table1
GROUP BY ID,
         Name, 
         SomeID
```

You can check a demo on SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47bb33/3).

Answer (score 0):

Try using group by clause in your query. Group your query by SomeId in your result set to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by Clause

```
select
id,
name,
sum(Score) as total,
SomeID
from table_name
group by name,SomeID,ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to produced the above, then you are basically trying to do:

```
SELECT 
id, name, sum(score), some_id
FROM table1
group by id, name,some_id
```

As you have stated, this isn't a table but a join result.
If the join result looks something like (could be anything).

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.name, table2.score, table1.some_id
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id
```

All you need to do is wrap is query with a join and give it an alias.

```
SELECT 
x.id, x.name, x.sum(score), x.some_id
FROM 
(SELECT table1.id, table2.name, table2.score, table1.some_id
FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.table1_id) x
GROUP BY x.id, x.name, x.some_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use aggregate function of database:

```
 SELECT ID, Name,SUM(Score) as "SUM(Score)",SomeID
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY ID,Name,SomeID
 ORDER BY 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Things are this simple:

```
SELECT ID, Name,SUM(Score),SomeID
 FROM table_name
 GROUP BY SomeID;
```